# HTML5 History API: go back and don't allow going forward (popState?)

Tags: ajax, html, back, forward, html5-history

I have a `webpage` that shows user information. I'm using `ajax` to allow the user to modify this data without changing the webpage.

The structure is really simple:

-When the user goes to profile he can see his data.

-If the user clicks the Edit button, a form is seen to modify the data.

-If the user sends the form, the data is saved and the static data is shown again (updated). **The user shouldn't be able to go back to the edit page using the `Back` button.**

-If the user clicks back when he is editting, the static data is shown again.

-If the user clicks back when he is seeing the static data, he should **always** go back to the previous page (not profile).

I'm using `HTML5 History API` to handle the `Back` button clicks. I'm having problems when the user submits the data, since I want him to go back to the previous state (not editing) without being able to go forward. This is waht I'm doing right now:

```
// Edit button clicked.
function edit1(){
    history.pushState("edit", null, "");
    showForm();
}

window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    var HistoryState = history.state;
    if(HistoryState == null){
       showStaticData();
    }
    else if(HistoryState == "edit1"){
        showForm();
    }
});

$('#myForm').submit(function () {

    ...

    history.back(); // CODE TO DO WHEN THE FORM HAS BEEN SUBMITTED

    return false;
});
```

If I use history.back() like I'm doing in the code above everything works fine except for the fact that the user is able to click `Forward` button. If I use a replaceState or pushState, the `Forward` button is disabled, but then the user can click the `Back` button and stay in the same page (I don't want that).

Is there any way to disable the `Forward` button without adding a new state? (I don't want the user to click `Back` and stay in the same page)

Answer (score 0):

### Use virtual states

A virtual state is a state that you explicity set as a "non displayable state": their main goal is to reset the forward states. 
I call these specific virtual states "removed" states.

I have used that principle for several web applications, and it works perfectly.

It's like pushing states that will not make your application move, but clear history State.

history.pushState({removed:true}, 'yourcurrenttitle','yourcurrenturl');

**On the popstate events**, make your script NOT launch the usual behaviour if these removed states are encountered.

---

### Notes

- Any new pushState while being on a removed:true history.state should be transformed to a replaceState
- You will have to handle the problem of skipping these removed states if you allow your application to remove a state between two others
- You will have to deal with the initial (document.ready) cases when the user comes on a removed (virtual) state. In my case I am redirecting the user on a "real" standard state to avoid that problem and not have an history filled with removed states. That is, if you try to handle the F5 (reload page) feature of the browser.